# Windows Authentication from Application outside of Domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

Okay so I have sort of a different question.

We have an ASP.NET MVC application that will be using windows authentication.  This is not an issue.  The problem is this will be accessed by both people inside the domain, and an application calling it outside the domain.  So the other application is supposed to provide 5 different parameters to my application: Username, password, RecordingID, a User, and then the system.

Originally they were just going to be passing a RecordingID and I was just going to accept that into the URL, and allow them the audio player to be a able to listen to this recording.  Now I have to accept all of the 5 above.  The Username and password is supposed to be used to authenticate this application, and it will be in our active directory.  I will use the recording ID provided to retrieve the correct recording for them.  The user and system are just for logging in our database.

I am stuck on the best way to receive this information from the external application.  Any sort of forms authentication for the external application will probably not work either.  So if there is a good way to receive this information from an external application I would really appreciate it.  Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered using Federation? [ADFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory_Federation_Services)

Answer (score 0):

A federated authentication service is the way to achieve this. Basically the user tries to access the site, and their client gets sent ot the federated service.

the client asks "how can I authenticate myself for the site?"
the service says "either windows auth or [some other kind of authentication]"
the client says either "great, here's my credentials" or gets sent to some external login to get credentials, and send those the the federated service.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I will talk with our Sys Admins and see if that is an option for us.